# Image scaling issues in Gstreamer-pipeline

Tags: python, opencv, camera, gstreamer, video-capture

**Hello,**

I have troubles in using a Gstreamer pipeline and my RPi v2.1 camera module to properly capture images. My pipeline is defined as such:

```
def gstreamer_pipeline(capture_width=720, capture_height=405, display_width=1280, display_height=720, framerate=21, flip_method=0):   
    return ('nvarguscamerasrc ! ' 
    'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), '
    'width=(int)%d, height=(int)%d, '
    'format=(string)NV12, framerate=(fraction)%d/1 ! '
    'nvvidconv flip-method=%d ! '
    'video/x-raw, width=(int)%d, height=(int)%d, format=(string)BGRx ! '
    'videoconvert ! '
    'video/x-raw, format=(string)BGR ! appsink'  % (capture_width,capture_height,framerate,flip_method,display_width,display_height))
```

When I, as in this example, set a lower capture size than a display size, it outputs an error. This setup is necessary for me though, because I want to capture low-res images and still want to see them in a nice big window. I'm avoiding the method of scaling every frame down, I'm sure this has got a more efficient solution.
If someone knows what to do, please can you share it?

*Thanks for the answers in advance!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`appsink` itself does not display anything. So what is your display method? In general if you don't want to scale in your GStreamer pipeline whatever is displaying your data is responsible for the scaling. Usually this is done on the GPU context of a GUI framework like Gtk/Qt.

Comment: For displaying, I use OpenCV: cv2.imshow('frame', frame) and then cv2.waitKey()

Comment: So then Opencv should have an option to scale a low resolution image to something bigger. In GStreamer you cannot just randomly give and chnage in resultion without a scaler and hope it does something.